# iOS : Can't play sound when the application is in the background

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

With [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound) and [react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer), I want to play a sound after 10 seconds delay.

Here is my very simple code :

```
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer'
import Sound from 'react-native-sound'

Sound.setCategory('Playback')
const soundEnd = new Sound('end.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE)

const Timer = () => {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const timeoutId = BackgroundTimer.setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('END setTimeout')
        soundEnd.play(() => {})
      }, 10000)

      return () => {
        BackgroundTimer.clearTimeout(timeoutId)
      }
    },
    []
  )
}
```

- Everything works fine on Android and iOS when the app is in the foreground: the sound is played and the `console.log('END setTimeout')` is displayed
- But when the application is in the background **on iOS the sound is not played** (but the `console.log('END setTimeout')` is displayed well)

Can you help me ? According to [react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer), the sounds are supposed to play in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on ios, you need to first enable UIBackgroundModes from Xcode and then add this in Info.plist.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/302

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but it does not solve the problem :/

Comment: @Gaylord.P check screenshot it's from react-native-sound lib

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I also had to add "processing" to the list :)